# PIV Smartcard Authentication ASP.NET - IE vs Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, ssl, smartcard

I am having some issues with PIV Smartcard authentication with IE11 vs Chrome. configurations in IIS is setup to prompt (required) for client certificate and is using SSL. In Chrome, the web app loads and prompts user for PIV certificate selection/pin and authenticates through. In Internet Explorer, there is no prompt for PIV cert and goes directly to a "This page can't be displayed."

Background:
Need to incorporate PIV Card authentication for an asp.net web app. The authentication method essentially reads certificate information, retrieves/filters for Unique ID, then cross references with database to authenticate.

Why would it work in Chrome and not in IE11? I've been stuck for awhile trying to figure this out and can't find anything around the web or forums. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you find any solutions in the end? We've had to ask our clients to use Chrome + a USB external card reader as the inbuilt DELL card readers don't work with IE for some reason.